# iteration of Java Map - Error in showing the array elements

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I have a hashmap whose value is an array. When I run the below code, the contents of the tempAr[0] and tempAr[1] are showed correctly. However, the iterator does not show the elements of the array accurately. Your help is most appreciated.

```
 Map<String, double[]> m1 = new HashMap<String, double[]>();

 double[] tempAr = new double[2];
 String mykey;

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {                         
         mykey = "Key" + i + j;
         tempAr[0] = i;
         tempAr[1] = j;

        System.out.println(" Now key is " + mykey + " and i is "
                + tempAr[0] + " j is " + tempAr[1]) ;
        mz.put(mykey, tempAr);
    }
}

Iterator<Entry<String, double[]>> it = mz.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, double[]> pair = (Map.Entry<String, double[]>) it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = "); // + pair.getValue());
    double[] value = (double[]) pair.getValue();

    for(double str : value) {
        System.out.println(str + "\t");
    }
}
```

Could you please help?

Comment: what does it show? can you elaborate more on what you expect and what you actually get?

Comment: why the nested loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are reusing the array, so you are overwriting the previously set values.

Putting something into a map (or list, set, array etc) doesn't copy that thing: it simply places a reference to that thing into the map. As such, you will see subsequent updates in the thing in the map.

Declare `double[] tempAr` inside the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    // ...
    double[] tempAr = {i, j};
    mz.put(mykey, tempAr);
  }
}
```